# C# Kestrel Web API - How is a Stream handled in POST

Tags: c#, .net, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to build a web api that a user can send some data to.

I'm using Swagger/OpenAPI to define the API and generate the code for it:

```
 requestBody:
    content:
        application/octet-stream
            schema:
               type: string
               format: binary
```

That produces the following function:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route and other stuff]
public abstract Task<IActionResult> SendDataStream([[FromBody] System.IO.Stream body);
```

And my Controller implementation works, and I can read the stream and send it to Azure blob storage. All good.

My question is where does the actual data get stored when I make the HTTP request?

On Machine A, I have, say, a 1 GB file, and on Machine B I have this server. When Machine A calls makes this POST request with content of that file, how does the data actually make it to Machine B, and where does Machine B put it while the call gets handled by the Controller?

Comment: In memory, or disk if it has to page it

Comment: Or nowhere if the data is still in flight (ie the client hasn't finished sending it yet).

Comment: There is no single correct answer anyone can give because it depends on your computer, your OS, how you configured Kestrel, amongst other things. (Kestrel is cross-platform, and supports things like `libuv` which behave differently to "normal" BSD Sockets, for example)

Comment: I had a quick look at Kestrel's sources and it looks like it it's 100% in-memory, with no 
request (nor response) message body  "overflow" buffering to disk - see the usage of `InitialStreamWindowSize` in `/src/Servers/Kestrel/` [in the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/d4baf3eb83b87d2eda40d7e588664652d3262ed0/src/Servers/Kestrel).

Comment: ...but I note that regardless of the web-server being used (IIS, HTTP.sys, Kestrel, etc), ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core assume responsibility for buffering stream "overflow" data to disk: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/20001: _"Where does the buffer go"_